# Scraping table contents from coingecko using beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, syntax-error

This is the code/output I got by referencing here: [scraping coins market with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59636476/scraping-coins-market-with-beautifulsoup).
However, I cannot make this code run:

```
url = 'https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum'
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")

data = []
for tr in soup.select('tr[class]'):
    if 'sponsored' in tr['class']:
       continue
    _, Exchange, Pair, Price, Spread, +2%Depth, -2%Depth, 24hVolume, Volume%, LastTraded, TrustScore,  *_ = tr.select('td')

    data.append( (Exchange.get_text(strip=True),
                  Pair.get_text(strip=True),
                  Price.get_text(strip=True),
                  Spread.get_text(strip=True),
                  +2%Depth.get_text(strip=True),
                  -2%Depth.get_text(strip=True),
                  24hVolume.get_text(strip=True),
                  Volume%.get_text(strip=True),
                  LastTraded.get_text(strip=True),
                  TrustScore.get_text(strip=True),
              ) )
```

This is the error I get:

```
     """File "C:\Users\Computer\PycharmProjects\new\gecko.py", line 22
      _, Exchange, Pair, Price, Spread, +2%Depth, -2%Depth, 24hVolume, Volume%, LastTraded,TrustScore,  *_ = tr.select('td')
                                                              ^
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT:**

I edited the code based on the first answer, I didnt get any error but only a blank square bracket shows up. Here is the edited code:

```
    _, exchange, pair, price, spread, depth0, depth1, volume0, volume1, lasttraded, trustscore,  *_ = tr.select('td')

    data.append( (exchange.get_text(strip=True),
              pair.get_text(strip=True),
              price.get_text(strip=True),
              spread.get_text(strip=True),
              depth0.get_text(strip=True),
              depth1.get_text(strip=True),
              volume0.get_text(strip=True),
              volume1.get_text(strip=True),
              lasttraded.get_text(strip=True),
              trustscore.get_text(strip=True),
              ) )
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your variable names there are some rules for:

- must start with a letter or the underscore character
- cannot start with a number
- can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (A-z, 0-9, and _ )
- are case-sensitive

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, it only get rid of the error but the result only shows blank square bracket.

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus . To keep the post clean please avoid updates that changes the focus, while your inital issue was answered. thanks